# Can't upvote a comment when reviewing close votes

Tags: support, bug

When reviewing close votes, I'm often upvoting already existing comments. However, since we're out of beta, this is no longer possible.

I'm talking about comments to questions. I see the comments, but the clicks are not working. I don't even see the little arrow and the flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voting is only enabled for comments in the First Posts and Late Answers queues, where it counts as a review action.

To vote on comments on posts in the other queues, you can use the link to the post on the left-hand side to open up the default view.